# niUiSlider link and make the percent sum of two sliders 100

Tags: nouislider

I have two noUiSlider's, both of which should equal 100%. So if slider1 is moved from 30% to 40%, slider2 should automatically move from 70% to 60%, and visa-versa.

In the noUiSlider documentation there is a `crossUpdate` code example, [HERE](http://refreshless.com/nouislider7/examples/#section-lock), for linking two sliders so they move dependant of each other. However the example shows the sliders moving in the same direction. And because this code is something I've never come across before, I've tried moving numbers around but still I can't get the sliders to move inversely.

HERE is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LukeMcLachlan/0ny6q375/2/

The crossUpdate function, which is where the solution lay, is as follows

```
function crossUpdate ( value, handle, slider ) {
    // If the sliders aren't interlocked, don't
    // cross-update.
    if ( !lockedState ) return;
    // Select whether to increase or decrease
    // the other slider value.
    var lValue = slider1.is(slider) ? 1 : 0,
        hValue = lValue ? 0 : 1;
    // Modify the slider value.
    value -= ( values[hValue] + values[lValue] );
    // Set the value
    $(this).val( value );
}
```

If anyone can help me solve this I will be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it appears that the answer is significanly simpler than having to use the code in my original fiddle.

This is the code I use to intialise my two sliders. The important thing is `animate: false`, as the documentation states, so that there isn't a lag when the other slider moves:

```
$("#hardwood").noUiSlider({
    start: 100,
    step: 1,
    animate: false,
    connect: 'lower',
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0
    }),
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
});
$("#softwood").noUiSlider({
    start: 0,
    step: 1,
    animate: false,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0
    }),
    connect: 'lower',
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
});
```

and the bit that does the moving is below:

```
$("#hardwood").Link('lower').to($("#hardwoodpercent"));
$("#softwood").Link('lower').to($("#softwoodpercent"));
$('#hardwood').on('slide', function(){
    var hardcalc = 100 -  $('#hardwood').val();
    $('#softwood').val(hardcalc);
});
$('#softwood').on('slide', function(){
    var softcalc = 100 -  $('#softwood').val();
    $('#hardwood').val(softcalc);
});
$('#hardwoodpercent').on('change', function(){
    var softcalc = 100 -  $('#hardwoodpercent').val();
    $('#softwood').val(softcalc);
});
$('#softwoodpercent').on('change', function(){
    var softcalc = 100 -  $('#softwoodpercent').val();
    $('#hardwood').val(softcalc);
});
```

I am not a whiz kid at coding but this works without console errors for two sliders.

Updated the fiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/LukeMcLachlan/0ny6q375/4/.

EDIT:

I have had to edit this answer, to take into consideration the fact that the user may well change the values via the input fields, instead of via the slider.